# Google Places API Web Services - Place Searches, location not specified as latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, google-maps, coordinates, google-places-api, currentlocation

I am building an ios app with Google Maps, to show nearby places at my current location. To accomplish this I first used Place Picker. Unfortunately it can't filter the type of places. So instead of this I used Google Places API Web Services. With Place Search I made a HTTP URL request, and could filter it to the type of places I want. However I must give the location in latitude and longitude. And the problem is I want to show nearby places with a specific type of place at my current location. For my current location I use Current Place from Google Places API ios. How can I give the coordinates of my current location in my HTTP URL request? I first thought of typing in self.latitude and self. longitude in the part of location in my HTTP URL, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Here is my explanation and code, if someone encounters the same problem.

To have the coordinate of your current location in your url you put the url in the CLLocationManager function.

And for the latitude and longitude for the coordinate in the url you replace it with placeholders. Like so: location=(latitude),(longitude)

before (latitude) and (longitude) you have to add a backslash. I don't know why it isn't showing a backslash.